# How to fix KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE BSOD when connecting to 5Ghz wireless access point

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, bsod

When I'm connecting to my home's 5Ghz wireless access point with my Windows 10 v.1607 desktop computer I always get a BSOD about KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE after typing the AP's password.

I didn't got any problem using Ethernet or a standard 2.4Ghz access point.
Moreover, after this BSOD encounters, the BIOS stands more longer.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide a link to at least a mini-dump or two when this happens.  Anything under \windows\minidump\?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've finally fixed it by making a Creators Update's clean install.

Comment: Can you explain this so that it will be useful to somebody else in the future?